# Why do my items not align properly?

Tags: itemize

I am writing a document and I need to itemize a few formulas with normal text in the same line. Only when I do this the bullets do not align and it gets all messed up. Could anyone maybe take a look and help me?

This is the code I am using

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
    subject to:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item $\sum\limits_{j \in P} r_{ij}*x_j \leq a_i$, for all i \in R
        \item $x_j \leq d_j$, for all j \in P
        \item $x_j \geq 0$, for all j \in P
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

As you can see it is not ideal.

Comment: Please, edit your question to add a full Minimal Working Example, starting by `\documentclass` and ending by `\end{document}` with every package you use. This could help to understand your issue.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Will do, forgot about that!

Comment: Don't you want to use math mode after the "for all", that is, `for all $i \in R$`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!!! The `\in` symbol needs a math environment so you should write `$i\in R$` and `$j\in P$`. BTW, you forgot `\begin{document}` in you MWE.

Comment: you are getting errors. Don't ignore them, after errors the output is basically undefined, tex tries to recover, but everything can be wrong.

Comment: I am unable to replicate the screenshot you posted, even after fixing the syntax errors. E.g., the screenshot you posted shows two bullet points, yet your code contains three `\item` statements. Please fix, i.e., please make sure that the code you post actually generates the screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to add missed `$ at math expressions at end of items:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document} % <---
    subject to:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item $\sum\limits_{j \in P} r_{ij}*x_j \leq a_i$, for all $i \in R$ % <---
        \item $x_j \leq d_j$, for all $j \in P$ % <---
        \item $x_j \geq 0$, for all $j \in P$ % <---
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
you may consider @Mico comment (thank you very much for it):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document} % <---
    subject to:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item $\sum\limits_{j \in P} r_{ij}*x_j \leq a_i$, for all $i \in R$ % <---
        \item $0 \leq x_j \leq d_j$, for all $j \in P$, % <---
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. I'd be tempted to replace the final two conditions with the single condition `\item $0 \leq x_j \leq d_j$ for all $j \in P$`.

Comment: Did you mean percent signs (%) rather than ampersands (&)?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, no, symbol %, which you see in code is for comments (it and content after it is not compiled). By this comment I only indicate, where I add `$`

Comment: @Mico, you are right. I will add your suggestion to answer. Thank you for upvote :-)

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, you are right! Corrected. Thank you for proofreading. I see that I wrongly said `ampersands`, but I mind dollar sign`$`  :-)